# Why do images saved to file differ in size from resources with imagejpeg()?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, compression, gd

I'm generating thumbnails from images automatically with the PHP GD library.
I then save the resized image to a file using `imagejpeg()` with 95% quality.

When I output this file using `echo file_get_contents($file)`, the filesize of the image is always about 2.5 - 4 times as large compared to when I directly output the resized image to the browser using `imagejpeg($resource_handle)`.

Google PageSpeed also tells me images could be compressed by 75%, which confirms the 1/4 ratio noticed.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Not sure that makes sense. Can suggest not using `file_get_contents` as `readfile` would be preferable and more performant - direct to output buffer.

Comment: @ficuscr That would indeed improve performance on the server side, but it changes nothing about the size of the output image.

Comment: Show me.  Give me proof of what you are describing. Use a small 5x5 pixel image.  Share the output. What makes up the extra bits? Is the persisted file not getting compressed perhaps?

Comment: I can't think of a way to 'prove' what I am describing, but I have found it to be consistent across around 50 different images. The image that is saved to a file is saved with 5% compression, whereas the other is not compressed at all. In both cases I use imagejpeg(). I would like to know if saving to a file instead of directly outputting makes a difference for the file size of the imagejpeg() function.

Comment: @ficuscr Thank you for your help, I found the answer in the documentation of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) mentions that the default (without passing the quality argument) quality setting is around 75%.

This explains why outputting an image directly without any other arguments passed to `imagejpeg()` results in a smaller image then when setting a quality higher than 75 manually.

Answer (score 0):

The "quality" setting is meaningless term in JPEG. It is merely a simplification used by some encoders to select quantization tables. One encoders' 75 can be entirely different from another encode's 75.

To figure this out you would need to look at and compare

1. The sampling rates;
2. The quantization tables; and
3. Huffman tables

used in the two images.